# default icons for file types with SonataMediaBundle

Tags: symfony-sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I'm using SonataMediaBundle and I don't want to generate icons for certain file types (e.g. pdf, xls, doc). I want to use a default icon (e.g. [image: pdf icon]).

I've been reading the Sonata Media [documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/helpers.html#thumbnails-for-files), and I *believed* that I need something like this:

`web/uploads/media/media_bundle/images/default_pdf/file.png` or
`web/uploads/media/sonatamedia/files/default_pdf/file.png`

neither of which work.

On the chance that `<format>` meant "small" or "large", I also tried this:

`web/uploads/media/media_bundle/images/default_small/file.png`

which I assumed would mean that `file.png` would be shown for every file, regardless of mime-type, if a small icon were required and the file instance didn't have a custom one. I also tried using `admin` instead of `default` as the context. No dice.

The icon src is always `/uploads/media/sonatamedia/files/admin/file.png`- which being an absolute path, does not actually exist.

My icon files are 45px wide, which I have set in config.yml:

```
        formats:
            small: { width: 45 , quality: 70}
            big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}
            pdf: { width: 45 , quality: 70} //tried with and without this line
```

File permissions are 644 and the cache has been cleared. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs, the example config shows:

```
cdn:
    server:
        path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/
```

I needed

```
cdn:
    server:
        path: /ACC/web/uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/
```

because my site's base url is something like http://example.com/ACC I hope this is useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your document is in the default context

```
{% thumbnail media, 'big' %}
```

will give you an image path like this

```
/uploads/media/sonatamedia/files/default_big/file.png
```

You just have to copy **file.png** in **/uploads/media/sonatamedia/files/default_big/** and it works.

Edit :
Personally I went CSS.

Template :

```
<a href="{{ path('sonata_media_download', {'id': media|sonata_urlsafeid }) }}"
class="downloadLink">Download {{media.name}}
</a>
```

CSS :

```
.downloadLink{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 62px;
    background: #fff url(../../bundles/mybundle/images/icons/fileIcon.png) left top no-repeat;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the src is an absolute path.  If the `{%thumbnail%} helper generated a path *relative to the base url*, I'd be all set.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah. Its hardcoded in Sonata source like:

```
// @todo: fix the asset path
$path = sprintf('sonatamedia/files/%s/file.png', $format);
```